# Capturing events in ngTable

Tags: underscore.js, ngtable

This ngTable [demo](http://ng-table.com/#/events/demo-subscribe) that shows capturing events uses `underscore.js` (for example `_.partial` )and I'm trying to run it without this dependency.

In this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gfJlj39s2sLeN5olaT4M?p=preview) I have a simplified version (without `underscore.js`) that works (look at the console log) but I'm also getting an ngTable error `Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`.

What's wrong with this code? how not to include `underscore.js`?

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myCtl" ng-app="app">
   <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="u in $data">
                <td title="'User ID'">{{ u.uid }}</td>
                <td title="'Name'">{{ u.nm }}</td>
                <td title="'Group'">{{ u.ugr }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope, NgTableParams,ngTableEventsChannel) {

      $scope.data = [{
          uid: 'User 1',
          nm: 'Name 1',
          ugr: 'Group 1'
      }, {
          uid: 'User 2',
          nm: 'Name 2',
          ugr: 'Group 2'
      }]; 

      var tableEvents = [];

      function subscribeToTable(tableParams){
          var logAfterCreatedEvent = logEvent (tableEvents, "afterCreated");
          ngTableEventsChannel.onAfterCreated(logAfterCreatedEvent, $scope, $scope.tableParams);
          var logAfterReloadDataEvent = logEvent ( tableEvents, "afterReloadData");
          ngTableEventsChannel.onAfterReloadData(logAfterReloadDataEvent, $scope, $scope.tableParams);
      }

      function logEvent(list, name){
         console.log(">>>>>>> " + name);
      }

      $scope.$watch("tableParams", subscribeToTable);

      $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
          count: 5
      }, {
          data: $scope.data
      });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes, that code can't work. You define two callbacks by giving ngTable a callback function name, but instead of giving it the reference to the functions, you are giving it the return value:

```
var logAfterCreatedEvent = logEvent (tableEvents, "afterCreated");
var logAfterReloadDataEvent = logEvent ( tableEvents, "afterReloadData");
```

The function `logEvent` does not return anything, therefore `logAfterCreatedEvent` and `logAfterReloadDataEvent` are `undefined`.

```
ngTableEventsChannel.onAfterCreated (
     logAfterCreatedEvent, 
     $scope, 
     $scope.tableParams
);

ngTableEventsChannel.onAfterReloadData (
     logAfterReloadDataEvent, 
     $scope, 
     $scope.tableParams
);
```

And with that, Angular falls flat as it tries to call your callbacks.

One fix would be to rewrite `logEvent()` into a function that returns a callback function:

```
  function logEvent(list, name){
     var that = this;
     that.list = list;
     that.name = name;
    return function() {
     console.log(">>>>>>> " + that.name);
    };
  }
```

[Here's a fixed version on JSBin](https://jsbin.com/quwemuyico/edit?js,console,output)